# SVG "Smooth curve" clarification

Tags: svg, language-lawyer, bezier

In the [W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataLinetoCommands) for SVGs, I read for 'S' and 's':

> (x2 y2 x y)+
>
> Draws a cubic Bézier curve from the current point to (x,y). **The first control point is assumed to be the reflection of the second control point on the previous command relative to the current point.** (If there is no previous command or if the previous command was not an C, c, S or s, assume the first control point is coincident with the current point.) (x2,y2) is the second control point (i.e., the control point at the end of the curve). S (uppercase) indicates that absolute coordinates will follow; s (lowercase) indicates that relative coordinates will follow. **Multiple sets of coordinates may be specified to draw a polybézier.** At the end of the command the new current point becomes the final (x,y) coordinate pair used in the polybézier.

In the case of a polybezier, does the "current point" or "previous command" change during this subpath?

In other words, does implicitly calculated first control point ever change during a S or s subpath if multiple sets of coordinates are specified?

The standard says "at the *end of the [S or s] command*", so I suspect not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, or what you mean by "change".

The following example:

```
M 0,0 S 100,100, 120,120, 200,200, 220,220
```

is considered to be a shorthand for:

```
M 0,0 S 100,100, 120,120 S 200,200, 220,220
```

So when you get to the second set of S coordinates (the 200s), the "previous command" is considered to be the "S 100,100 120,120", *not* the "M 0,0".

Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added an example. Consider `M 0,0 S 100,100, 120,120 S 200,200, 220,220, 250,260 300,300`. What is the "previous command" used to calculate the first control point for `250,260 300,300`.

Comment: "S 200,200,220,200" is the previous command.  The calculated first control point for the last S will be 240,240, which is 200,200 "reflected" past 220,220.  So the last command in your example is equivalent to "C 240,240 250,260, 300,300".